# Insert data into a table when the data is inserted into another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, insert, jobs

I have two identical tables, each in a different database on a different server. The two servers are on the same network. Data is inserted more often into one of the tables, I want the same data to be inserted into the other table when it's inserted into the first table.

Is there way to do it instead of merging tables and SSIS?

Comment: Why do you need two identical sets of data on the same network? Why not just have one set of data? If you are dead set on duplicating your data you could look into replication, or maybe even insert triggers.

Answer (score 0):

If the two servers are linked servers, you can create a trigger on the first table for inserting the same data in the second table. 
the code would be something like below

```
CREATE TRIGGER <trigger name>
ON <Table1>
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO <server name>.<database name>.<schema>.<table2>
SELECT * FROM INSERTED
END
```